# Would c != 0 actually disprove the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyre conjecture rather than prove it?

Tags: number-theory, taylor-expansion, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, l-functions

**Background:**
The Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture states that the Taylor expansion around the point $s=1$ of the L-function of an elliptic curve $E$ has the form
$$c(s-1)^r+\text{higher order terms},$$
where $c$ is a constant not equal to zero, and $r$ is the rank of the curve. This implies that the L-function
$$L(E,1)=\prod_p F_p(1)^{-1} \sim (k(\log X)^r )^{-1},$$
where $F_p(1)=N_p/p$, $k$ is a constant (without any non-zero restrictions), $N_p$ is the number of solutions $E (mod p)$, and $p$ are the prime numbers. The conjecture states that $L(E,1)=0$ if and only if the number of points on $E$ is infinite (see Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer’s paper “Notes on Elliptic Curves. II”).

The implication is clear that when the number of points is infinite, then it could increase faster than the infinite primes, as if $N_p$ in
$$F_p(1)^{-1}=p/N_p$$
continues to grow faster than $p$, as $p$ approaches infinity, then $L(E,1)=0$. But that’s only half of the conjecture. The reverse implication (“and only if”) is not as clear to me; that is, if $N_p$ is finite, then once passed the last $N_p$ in the list of
$$L(E,1)=\prod_p p/N_p$$
the primes $p$ will still continue to grow to infinity such that $L(E,1)$ too will grow to infinity (an infinite product over a finite product equals an infinite product). This seems contradictory to the conjecture based on the Modularity Theorem that would imply that $L(E,1)$ is finite for all elliptic curves.

**Question:**
If one could prove that
$$T_{L(E,1)}=c(s-1)^r+\text{higher order terms},$$
where $T_{L(E,1)}$ is the Taylor expansion of $L(E,1)$, and $c\neq 0$, would it actually prove the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture, or would it disprove it?

**Discussion:**
If the answer to the above is “it proves”, then one could prove that the conjecture is false in just one sentence. I will show.

In reading Gross and Zagier’s 1983 paper “Heegner Points and Derivatives of L-Series”, they prove that there are an infinite number of points on rank one modular curves when $L(E,1)=0$ but $L'(E,1)\neq 0$. But I do not see that they proved $L(E,1)=0$ is possible for rank 1 modular curves, only that if $L(E,1)=0$ *is* possible but $L'(E,1)\neq 0$, then there will exist an infinite number of points on the curve. This is a subtle detail but important. Much (if not all) interpretation on this that I can find suggests exactly the opposite of what I am raising. But similarly, in reading Kolyvagin’s 1989/90 paper “Finiteness of E(Q) and III(E,Q) for a Subclass of Weil Curves,” which is typically thought to prove the reverse implication, Kolyvagin proves for modular curves, when rank equals zero, $L(E,1)\neq 0$, and when rank equals one, $L(E,1)=0$ and $L'(E,1)\neq 0$. This does imply the reverse implication of $L(E,1)=0$ to rank 1, but it does not imply $c\neq 0$. It implies the contrary, so it seems to me.

The leading term of the Taylor expansion of a function is always the function itself at the point expanded around. If the leading term is zero, then all the remaining terms add up to zero. The conjecture predicts that the leading term of the Taylor expansion of the L-function of $E$ is $c(s-1)^0$, where at $s=1$, $(s-1)^0=1$, as any number raised to zero is one (by the order of arithmetic operations, the power is determined before even looking at what’s within the parentheses). Thus, if the first term is zero, then $c(s-1)^0=0$ implies $c=0$ (again because $(s-1)^0=1$), but this result says nothing about the BS-D conjecture itself, as by definition of the conjecture, $c$ cannot be zero.

However, following the Modularity Theorem from the mid-90s, all elliptic curves are now proven to be modular, and therefore all $L(E,s)$ are finite. This allows:

**Theorem:** If
$$T_{L(E,1)}=c(s-1)^r+\text{higher order terms},$$
where $T_{L(E,1)}$ is the Taylor expansion of $L(E,1)$, then $L(E,s)=0$ implies $c=0$, as the leading term of the series is always equal to the function itself at the point expanded around, and $c(s-1)^0=0$ implies $c=0$.

In other words, a contradiction would exist in the conjecture and therefore it is incorrect. That is, unless 1) I am mistaken (please point out where) or 2) the conjecture is incorrect if it can be proven that $$T_{L(E,1)}=c(s-1)^r+\text{higher order terms}$$ (proof by contradiction). But I am only asking if this would only disprove the reverse implication of the conjecture: the idea that no finite curves exist of greater than rank zero. The implication of infinite curves existing for rank greater than zero would still hold.

Lastly, please understand that I am 99% sure I am wrong about all of this above, but I cannot find where my error arises.

Comment: I don't understand your argument and I think you are confused by the meaning of "leading term." In this context it means the leading *nonzero* term, meaning that $c \neq 0$ by definition; the BSD conjecture predicts first that $r$ is the rank of $E$ and second also predicts the constant $c$. If $L(E, 1) = 0$ then the leading term isn't the constant term, it's the first nonzero term after that.

Comment: My apologies if what I wrote is confusing.  In my understanding, in a Taylor expansion around a point x = 1, the leading term of the Taylor expansion of f(1) is simply the value of the function itself at the center of the expansion, which is f(1). In other words, the leading term corresponds to the zeroth-order term in the Taylor series:

f(x) ≈ f(1) + f'(1)(x - 1) + f''(1)(x - 1)^2/2! + f'''(1)(x - 1)^3/3! + ...

The leading term is the constant term f(1), and it is the dominant term when you're very close to x = 1 in the Taylor expansion. It is the zeroth order term.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Jeff in that case, you've misunderstood the conjecture. The leading term there means the first non-zero term, not $f(1)$.

Comment: No, that is not what "leading term" means here. Again it refers to the leading nonzero term, and again, this means that $c \neq 0$ by definition.

Comment: @Qiaochu_Yuan, While I understand this for infinite points, I was hoping an answer could satisfy the questions raised in the above regarding finite curves.  If the leading term is the first term of the Taylor expansion at s=1 for a rank 0 curve (but not greater than rank 0), then L(E,1) should be finite, as Wiles' proof implies all elliptic curves are modular and thus all L(E,1) finite.  But it cannot be finite if rank = 0 at s=1, as it is conjectured that F_p(1)^-1 = p / N_p at s=1, where N_p is by definition finite, because the primes will continue to infinity. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mathmo123, the above question is for you as well.

Comment: $L(E, 1)$ is always finite. It is non-zero precisely when $E(\mathbb Q)$ is finite. Otherwise $L(E, 1) = 0$. Perhaps one issue is that your definition of $L(E, s)$ is only valid when $s$ has real part at least $3/2$. Wiles' proof means that $L(E, s)$ has analytic continuation to all of $\mathbb C$, but the formula won't be the same. (Just as $\zeta(-1)$ isn't really $1 + 2 + 3+ 4 +\cdots$.)

Comment: @MathMo123, thank you for getting back to me.  My question is in regards to s=1.  If L(E,1) is conjectured to be equal to the Product_p (p / N_p), and N_p is finite (E has a finite number of points, a rank 0 curve), and the number of p is infinite, how could L(E,1) be anything other than infinity for rank 0 curves if the conjecture is correct?  Again, I must be missing something, but something is not connecting with me in this.

Comment: That's my point. $L(E,1)$ is not $\prod_p{p/N_p}$, at least not literally. Just as $\zeta(-1)$ is not $1 + 2 + 3+ 4+\cdots$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thank you for taking interest.  According to Birch and Swinnerton-Dyre, they write in "Notes on Elliptic Curves II" on page 2, paragraph 2, L(E,1) is defined by Hecke, formerly as "L(E,1) = Product_p (N_p / p)^-1".  This is not an asymptotic equivalence, but a precise equality, such that Z_E,Q(s) = zeta(s) zeta(s-1) / L(E,s).  Therefore, it is not analogous to the analytic continuation of sum_(n=1) n^-s being equal to the sum outside of its region of convergence.

Comment: "Formally" in this case means "as a formal product", without paying attention to issues of convergence. In the same sense that formally, just by manipulating variables, $(1- x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$, even though the equality really only makes sense when $|x|<1$. See (2.3) in that paper, where they make clear that this is only an equality in a formal sense, not in a literal sense.

Comment: Tate famously said that the BSD conjecture "relates the behaviour of a function L at a point where it is not known to be defined to the order of a group that is not known to be finite". After Wiles, we now know that the $L$-function is defined at $s=1$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, I had my aha moment last night.  What was throwing me was your analogy regarding the harmonic series.  While sum_(n=1)^infinity n^-s can be thought of as the generalization of the harmonic series for all s, s=1 is a pole itself.  This is not the case with the BS-D, based on Wiles' proof, so I couldn't see what you were saying.  I can now look at what BS and D were thinking without knowing Wiles's proof.  And the way I understand it now from their POV is that f_p(s) must have an alternate form that too has a formal definition, but this alternate form must be finite for rank 0.